# How to fast-forward dev HEAD to master HEAD?

Tags: git-merge

When using Gitlab or Github to manage code, after merged a merge request or pull request for `dev` to `master`, the HEAD of `dev` always fall behind HEAD of `master` one commit because of the default merge command is `git merge` with `--no-ff`.

How to make HEAD of `dev` to be the same as HEAD of `master`?

I find some command online:

```
git checkout dev
git merge master --ff-only
```

Is it right? Is it reasonable to merge master into dev?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never merge public branch into your own feature branch.

Try `git rebase master`